How to add vertices?

I was making a football stadium in blender, and I wanted to make the roof of it something like you can see in the reference, I thought if I pull edit the vertices a bit upwards and sculpt it smooth to match the reference it would do it but when I pulled it out it didn't leave enough geometry for me to sculpt on there, so this means I have to add vertices between the red highlighted thing as the white thing being the added vertices, I don't know how to do it. Help... (BTW I'm a very new guy to blender and this is my very first project in blender so please don't judge me).

In Edit Mode, select the 3 "vertical" edges (the ones cut by your white line), then go to the menu "Edge->Subdivide".

Side note: I would recommand to use an Array modifier to model only an angular segment/pattern, then to duplicate it, instead of modelling 360°. Out of experience, it worths to spend some time identifying symmetries and duplicates. As modifiers are not destructive, corrections of the basic pattern are easily propagated.

Putting a MultiResolution Modifier on the mesh is a great way to solve that problem.
You may also find good use with the Cloth Brush in Sculpt Mode.
